# How to input integer vector with Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am implementing a kind of Neural Network, in particular a Multilayer Perceptron to detect the language of the several sentences. In particular, I am using Tensorflow in Python 3.X.

Previously, I have built a 2-gram file from several sentences in 10 languages. 2-gram file is using as input of my Neural Network. For example, a sentences like "I like footbal" could be ['1','15','3',...,'30'].

As tutorial, I am following [the next](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/3_NeuralNetworks/multilayer_perceptron.ipynb).

That example is using MINST as you can see at import section:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
```

My question is, how can I pass this vector to my Neural Network?

In the example, I can see the following statement:

```
batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
```

And, this other one:

```
_, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
```

There, it is difficult to understand because I can not know which is the type of batch_x and batch_y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can be in numpy or list format, but when you feed it with feed_dict, it turns to tensor object,

You can pass it by feed_dict, as `sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})`

Generally, you have data `x` and labels `y` and you want to train your network with `x` and calculate loss(or cost) based on `y`, now for training, you no need to feed whole `x` to network, but instead, we divide `x` to parts which called `batch` then, pick each `batch` and train the network (so each `batch` has `batch_x` for data and `batch_y` for labels), then go to next `batch`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understood that I have to get each sentences like integer vector (batch), and batch_x has all sentences like integer vector. I am going to use python list type of integers.